# Multiple lines in Azure Synapse/ADF expression builder

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I would like to have all lines showed inside of the expression builder. I want to avoid the following:

[image: Loses overview]

This works in pipeline runs, but is hard to debug and check.

I want the following, which is easy to read and debug:

[image: Multiline dynamic content]

Unfortunately this leads to newline characters being introduced in the resulting expression, which breaks the pipeline.

Any suggestions to achieve the above solution?

Comment: You can expand the dynamic content editor https://i.imgur.com/FLSOcLs.png

Comment: Thanks, this makes it better but it's still a wide and hard to read one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

**String interpolation** treats the `enter` as new line in result. As an alternative you can use `concat()` in dynamic content.

**Example:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]